# Applying enough heat (120 ° C) to shrinking tube without damaging the fletching

Tags: diy, arrows

I want to test a shrinking tube as my arrow winding. Commonly I've used the normal yarn and glue combination.

[image: Shrinking tube as winding]

However, I wonder how to apply enough heat (at least 120 ° C) to the tube without damaging the feathers? Like a lighter or candle easily ignite the feathers if you aren't careful enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A direct flame isn't a good way to set heat shrink tube as the flame is much too hot, making it very difficult to apply heat evenly without just melting the tube.

The ideal thing is a [hot air gun](https://youtu.be/qzTQaGxiUnk). You can get smaller more precise ones for fiddly electronics applications etc but for arrows a standard sized one should be fine and they generally aren't too expensive.

If you feel that there is still a risk of damaging the feathers then something like a small foil pie case with a hole in the middle could make a convenient heat shield.

Comment: A standard one with a low heat mode would work well.  There are some that only go hot enough for paint stripping and they char the heatshrink.  The little ones for electronics use are a perfect temperature but overpriced.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I ordered a hot air gun for 15 € and add a nozzle (which was also in the package). This nozzle controlled the air stream a little bit more. The lowest operation-level gives enough heat (about 300 ° C) for the shrinking tube. Due to the nozzle, I could easily apply heat to the tube but not to the feathers.

Comment: I would have just used a hair dryer if I didn't have a heat gun already.